# How to do a format check in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to allow people to register their vehicles in my system and I want to provide a format check, which is very similar to the format `LL-0000`.

Is it possible to get this done in the `models.py` or at least in the `forms.py`.

This is my models.py just in case you needed it.

```
class Vehicle (models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(VehicleModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    vehicle_colour = models.CharField(choices=COLOURS, max_length=10)
    vehicle_number = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I needed the format check for the `vehicle_number` field.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [Validator [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators) to your Model / Form field to perform such validation. A `ModelForm` will automatically run the validator or you can call `model_instance.full_clean()` to validate an instance yourself. An easy method for you would be to use the [`RegexValidator` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#regexvalidator) and simply write a regex to validate your values:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


vehicle_number_validator = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{4}$', message='Invalid Vehicle Number!')


class Vehicle (models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(VehicleModel, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    vehicle_colour = models.CharField(choices=COLOURS, max_length=10)
    vehicle_number = models.CharField(max_length=8, validators=[vehicle_number_validator])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Hey, this method seems to work perfectly fine but I forgot to mention I need it for 2 values. `LL-000` and `LLL-000`. How am is able to add both? @Abdul Aziz Barkat

Comment: @Najaaz can you specify more clearly what you mean by 2 values? Are you talking about the regex? The regex I give above matches 2 letters, a hyphen and then two digits, if you want something else please specify it (I can only guess if all you specify is `LL-000` and `LLL-000`). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Nop, i already figured it out, I just forgot we needed to do `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}-\d{4}$` . My code works perfectly fine thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **clean** method of forms.Form

```
import re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class VehicleForm(forms.Form):

    def clean_vehicle_number(self):
        vehicle_number = self.cleaned_data['vehicle_number']
        if (re.search(r'^[A-Z]{2}-\d{4}$', vehicle_number)):
            return vehicle_number
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Error message")
```

see for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Data validation is best handled in the forms, in this case you will want to use a regex validator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#regexvalidator

```
class VehicleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = ['vehicle_number', ...]

    vehicle_number = CharField(
        max_length=8,
        required=True,
        validators=[
           RegexValidator(
                regex='<your regex here>',
                message='Vehicle Number must be format ...',
                code='invalid_vehicle_number'
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Comment: Why do you say it's best handled in forms, when validators also exist for model fields?

Comment: Other data validation (e.g clean_<field_name>) happens in the form, so it keeps all of the validation in one place. Not only this, it allows finer control of when to apply the validator. If you want a second form, for say, foreign vehicles that dont have the same vehicle_number rules, you would need to overwrite the default behaviour of the field in the new ModelForm class with a new regex validator - at which point you would have validators in both the models and the forms which would be harder to keep track of. Fundamentally its semantics, and validators in models are perfectly valid.